# Which updates does rdpinit.exe 6.1.7601.23403 contain?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I have an issue that seems to be fixed by kb2682814, which lists the version of various rdp components to be 6.1.7601.21935 after update.

The actual version installed is 6.1.7601.23403. I cannot find any info on this version apart from it might be part of "Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1" (KB3125574).

I think the symptom described by the hotfix still exists despite of the higher version, so does this version actually contain the fix?

Comment: The file version included in the hot fix, for the behavior you describe was, `6.1.7601.21935`.  if your current file version is `6.1.7601.23403` it means the hotfix already included.  Don't ask me how I know this, because to put it simply, thats just how Microsoft updates components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see which update includes a file, run `regedit.exe` and go to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\`.

The RDPInit.exe is stored under `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..lications-clientsku_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23403_none_7d9460d975d9c0a0\rdpinit.exe`,

so when you look for `amd64_microsoft-windows-t..lications-clientsku_31bf3856ad364e35`, you see the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..lications-clientsku_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_9ed3b18a46ab4055`. Here regedit shows that the 6.1.7601.23403 comes from the Update [KB3125574(Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3125574/convenience-rollup-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1).

[image]

Follow those steps for all other files you want to see which KB includes the version.

Newer file versions always include older versions of the file, so your installed rdpinit.exe already includes the older fix.